# LD_PRELOAD doesn't affect dlopen() with RTLD_NOW

Tags: c, linux, shared-libraries, dlopen, ld-preload

If I use a function from a shared library directly, i.e. by declaring it in my code and linking during compile time, LD_PRELOAD works fine. But if I use `dlopen()`/`dlsym()` instead LD_PRELOAD has no effect!

The problem is that I want to debug a program that loads some plugins using `dlopen()`, and it uses absolute file names at that, so simply using `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` won't work.

Here's a sample code which illustrates the problem.

### ./libfoo.so

```
void foo() {
    printf("version 1\n");
}
```

### ./preload/libfoo.so

```
void foo() {
    printf("version 2\n");
}
```

### main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
void foo();
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    void (*pfoo)();
    foo(); // call foo() first so we are sure ./preload/libfoo.so is loaded when we call dlopen()
    pfoo = dlsym(dlopen("libfoo.so", RTLD_NOW), "foo");
    pfoo();
    return 0;
}
```

### command line

```
LD_PRELOAD=preload/libfoo.so LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ./a.out
```

### output

```
version 2
version 1
```

Why doesn't LD_PRELOAD affect `dlopen()`, and is there any way to redirect `dlopen()`, especially when using absolute paths?

Comment: You never call `pfoo` so that `main` cannot produce the specified output. Also, in order to reproduce the problem, you should specify the build commands (since they matter, see my answer).

Comment: It was a copy/paste mistake, sorry. That's what happens when you edit and reeedit a couple of times. Fixed now.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Specifying `LD_PRELOAD` will cause the loader to unconditionally load (and initialize) the indicated shared libraries prior to loading the main executable. This makes the symbols defined in the preloaded libraries available prior to linking `main`, allowing the interposition of symbols. [Note 1]

So, in your example, the call to `foo()` uses the *symbol* from the preloaded module, and `dlsym` would return the same symbol if you had called it with a NULL handle.

However, the call to `dlopen` does not take into account the symbol you are looking for (for obvious reasons). It just loads the indicated shared object or returns a handle to an already-cached version of the shared object. It does not add the module to a list of modules to load if necessary; it simply loads the module. And when you pass the returned handle to `dlsym`, `dlsym` looks in precisely that module in order to resolve the symbol, rather than searching the set of external symbols present in the executable. [Note 2]

As I mentioned, `dlopen` will not load the "same" shared object more than once, if it already has loaded the object. [Note 3]. However, the shared object in your `LD_PRELOAD` is called `preload/libfoo.so`, not `libfoo.so`. (ELF does not strip directory paths from shared object names, unlike certain other operating systems.) So when you call `dlopen("libfoo.so")`, the dynamic loader is not going to find any shared object named `libfoo.so` in the cache of loaded shared objects, and it will therefore look for that object in the filesystem, using the library search paths since the provided filename does not contain a `/`.

As it turns out, ELF does allow you to specify the name of a shared object. So you can set the name of the preloaded module to the name which you will later dynamically load, and then `dlopen` will return the handle to the preloaded module.

We start by correcting the version of `main.c` in the original question:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
void foo();
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    const char* soname = argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "libfoo.so";
    void (*pfoo)();
    pfoo = dlsym(NULL, "foo"); // Find the preloaded symbol, if any.
    if (pfoo) pfoo(); else puts("No symbol foo before dlopen.");
    void* handle = dlopen(soname, RTLD_NOW);
    if (handle) {
      pfoo = dlsym(handle, "foo"); // Find the symbol in the loaded SO
      if (pfoo) pfoo(); else puts("No symbol foo after dlopen.");
    }
    else puts("dlopen failed to find the shared object.");
    return 0;
}
```

This can be built without specifying any libraries other than libdl:

```
gcc -Wall -o main main.c -ldl
```

If we build the two shared libraries with no specified names, which is probably what you did:

```
gcc -Wall -o libfoo.so -shared -fPIC libfoo.c
gcc -Wall -o preload/libfoo.so -shared -fPIC preload/libfoo.c
```

then we observe that the `dlopen/dlsym` finds the symbol in the loaded module:

```
$ LD_PRELOAD=preload/libfoo.so LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ./main libfoo.so
version 2
version 1
```

However, if we assign the name being looked for to the preloaded shared object, we get a different behaviour:

```
$ gcc -Wall -o preload/libfoo.so -Wl,--soname=libfoo.so -shared -fPIC preload/libfoo.c
$ LD_PRELOAD=preload/libfoo.so LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ./main libfoo.so
version 2
version 2
```

That works because the `dlopen` is looking for the shared object named `libfoo.so`. However, it is more likely that an application loading plugins will use a filename rather than using the library search path. And that will cause the preloaded shared object to not be considered, because the names no longer match:

```
$ LD_PRELOAD=preload/libfoo.so LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ./main ./libfoo.so
version 2
version 1
```

As it happens, we can make this work by building the shared library with the name actually being looked for:

```
$ gcc -Wall -o preload/libfoo.so -Wl,--soname=./libfoo.so -shared -fPIC preload/libfoo.c
$ LD_PRELOAD=preload/libfoo.so LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ./main libfoo.so
version 2
version 2
```

That's a bit of a hack, IMHO, but it is acceptable for debugging. [Note 4]

#### Notes:

1. Consequently, the comment "call foo() first so we are sure ./preload/libfoo.so is loaded" is incorrect; the preloaded module is **pre**loaded, not added to a list of modules to load if necessary.
2. If you want `dlsym` to just look for a symbol, you can pass a `NULL` handle. In that case, `dlsym` will search in modules loaded by `dlopen` (including modules required by the module loaded by `dlopen`). But that's rarely what you want, since applications which load plugins with `dlsym` normally specify a particular symbol (or symbols) which the plugin must define, and these symbols will be present in every loaded plugin, making the lookup by symbol name imprecise.
3. This is not quite correct, but dynamic symbol namespaces are outside the scope of this answer.
4. Other hacks are possible, of course. You could, for example, interpose your own version of `dlopen` to override the shared object name lookup. But that's probably a lot more work than necessary.

Answer (score 1):

According to http://linux.die.net/man/3/dlopen

> The four functions dlopen(), dlsym(), dlclose(), dlerror() implement
>   the interface to the dynamic linking loader.

Whereas the `LD_PRELOAD` only affects the dynamic linker itself -- ie: ld.so (http://linux.die.net/man/8/ld.so).  The only way I can think of forcing `dlopen` to resolve as you want is through `chroot`.

Followup thought:

Another thought I just had, what if you write a wrapper that FIRST loads the correct `*.so` THEN invokes the program you are trying to redirect. Does this cause the child process to use the redirected `*.so` ?

Comment: 2 questions - what is the difference between the dynamic linker and the dynamic linking loader? And hasn't LD_PRELOAD already loaded the library by the time `dlopen()` is called? Actually this can be easily checked by changing the order and calling `foo()` before `dlopen()`, and I'll check shortly. Edit: I found about the difference - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10052464/difference-between-dynamic-loading-and-dynamic-linking

Comment: Answer to 1st question -- calling `dlopen()` is how you open a specific `*.so` file AS a dynamic link file.  It is the underlying mechanism used by `ld.so`.

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is that I want to debug a program that loads some plugins using dlopen(), and it uses absolute file names at that, so simply using `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` won't work.

Yep, `dlopen` does not do `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` search for paths with slashes.

You can override/superimpose `dlopen` itself to do that search for those specific plug-in paths.