# How do hello_xr (Openxr) sample retrieve the Vulkan API pointer for the Oculus Quest?

Tags: android, c++, vulkan, oculus, openxr

I always thought that on android platform we were supposed to load the pointer to Vulkan library using `dlopen()` and `dlsym()` (something like that:

```
libVulkan = dlopen("libvulkan.so", RTLD_NOW | RTLD_LOCAL);
vkEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties = reinterpret_cast<PFN_vkEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties(dlsym(libVulkan,"vkEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties"));
```

(source: https://github.com/SaschaWillems/Vulkan/blob/master/base/VulkanAndroid.cpp)

)

or by using the "vulkan_wrapper.h" dynamic loader (like in the Vulkan Android Samples by google https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vulkan-tutorials)

I was able to build and run the hello_xr sample on the oculus quest thanks to the blog of
Gayan Ediriweera (https://gayanediriweera.github.io/code/2021/04/06/how-to-run-helloxr-on-oculus-quest.html)

However when I look at the code for the hello_xr sample for vulkan I haven't seen call to dlopen() or dlsym(). For example at line 1287 (https://github.com/KhronosGroup/OpenXR-SDK-Source/blob/master/src/tests/hello_xr/graphicsplugin_vulkan.cpp), the sample call `vkEnumerateInstanceLayerProperties` but I don't see where the pointer for this base function is loaded which is confusing me.

What is the kind of black magic that is going on here ?
Does the OpenXR runtime load these under the hood or am I missing something in the code?

Thanks in advance for any help on this

Comment: Do you know what dlopen does? Do you know why you *don't* need to use dlopen to call printf?

Comment: @user253751 Isn't it for dynamically loading a shared library ? is the answer of the second question linked to the answer of this question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63306734/when-to-actually-use-dlopen-does-dlopen-means-dynamic-loading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to call a function from some library, there are two ways to do it:

1. Tell the compiler you want to use the library. Then, just use the function.
2. *Don't* tell the compiler you want to use the library. Instead, call `dlopen` to load the library and then call `dlsym` to look up the functions in the library, and call them.

The first way is the normal way to use a library. The second way is something you only do with a good reason - for example if you're not sure that the library is installed.

I would guess that Android has some good reason to use `dlopen` (perhaps old versions of Android don't have Vulkan installed?) and OpenXR does not.

Comment: Thanks for enlighten me. You're right. According to this https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/graphics/getting-started#using they use dlopen for retro compatibility with API bellow 23. I suppose there is no point doing it with OpenXR since older device won't probably support it.