# How to make a program link to a library at runing time instead of compile time?

Tags: c++, g++

How can I compile my program with this declaration files( .h files) without definitions files( .so files)? How to make a program link to a library at runing time instead of compile time?

I try to compile my program only with .h files, but g++ compiler with tell errors: cannot find the defination of function xxx.

Comment: Can you give us the code you used and the command you used to compile?

Comment: There is a way to do it, but it requires you to not call the functions of the library directly. Instead you need to create *pointers* to the functions, and initialize them when you actually load the library. It also requires you to know the *exact* [mangled name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling) of the function (which can change without notice). In short, using it with any kind of object member function will be a *mess* and a *lot* of work for no real upside. So lots of work to create something unmaintainable.

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem: why do you not have .so files available to link to? If nothing else, that populates the executable with a "I need this .so file" entry.

Comment: https://linux.die.net/man/3/dlsym ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When to actually use dlopen()? Does dlopen() means dynamic loading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63306734/when-to-actually-use-dlopen-does-dlopen-means-dynamic-loading)